# Confusion with app.use with Router() in express

Tags: node.js, express

I was learning Express in Node.js and came across Router() allowing us to modularize our routes. But than I found this code:

```
// we'll create our routes here

// get an instance of router
var router = express.Router();

...

// route with parameters (http://localhost:8080/hello/:name)
router.get('/hello/:name', function(req, res) {
    res.send('hello ' + req.params.name + '!');
});

// apply the routes to our application
app.use('/', router);
```

What confused me is that why we need to use app.use('/', router); to apply the routes. That is, what if we use app.get('/', router);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am giving you a simple code example to make you understand the use of express.Router(). Yes you are right that it helps in **modularization**. Actually it makes our main **app.js** file clean from all the routes. We just put all those routes based on their purposes in different files and require them when needed.
so suppose I have two files **app.js** and **register.js**

```
// app.js file's code goes here
let express = require("express")
let app = express()
let register = require("./routes/register")

app.use(register) // This will tell your app to import all those routes which are in register
```

```
// register.js file's code goes here
let express = require("express")
let router = express.Router()

router.get("/register", callback_function);
router.post("/register", callback_function);

module.exports = router;
```

So basically what I am trying to show is your **register.js** can contain all types of HTTP requests(GET, POST, PUT,...) and when we use **app.use(register)** this will handle all those routes. **app.get("route_path", callback_function)** is only for handling get requests to that path.

Answer (score 0):

Router is just a middleware of it's own. If you use `app.get('/', router)` you will use the router just for `GET` requests. Using `use` channels all requests there.

Answer (score 0):

When `app.use` is used then it handled all the HTTP methods, but when `app.get` is used it takes just `GET` method.

Added advantage to `app.use` is that route will match any path that follows its path immediately with a `/`.
For example:

```js
app.use('/v1', ...)
```

will match `/users`, `/users/accounts`, `/users/accounts/account-id`, and so on.